# Android Make Disappear or remove the blue dot on the map v2

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to replace the blue dot on the map of my app.
My intention is that instead of the usual blue dot, show an icon shaped plane.
I achieve this and it works perfectly as follows:

```
//...
GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

 try{
                    myPositionMarker.remove();
                } catch (Exception e){
                 //..
                }

                myPositionMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .flat(true)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.plane))
                        .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                                        .getLongitude())));
//...
}
```

As I said, this works fine, but now I see my icon and the blue dot:

[image]

I have tried many ways to do it, but can not find any that work.
There are many examples of removing the button "My Location" but I do not want to delete it.

I want to remove the blue dot.

[image]

I appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance and greetings

***UPDATE:**

Responding to the comment written by @tyczj i'm removing my location button as follows:

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
```

Thus, my location button is not visible, but the blue dot is visible.
Change the two boolean to false and then no longer works. No blue dot, but neither location update.
I'm a little confused. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: you cannot remove the blue dot without removing the my location button, you need to have your own button that does the same thing then

Comment: Even without Google's location button removing the blue dot does not seem possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to have "google's go-to-my-location-button" you have to have "google's blue dot". If you don't want "google's blue dot" you also will not have "google's go-to-my-location-button" and thus you'll have to implement it by yourself. Just add  [requestLocationUpdates (GoogleApiClient client, LocationRequest request, LocationListener listener)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener%29) to track user location and add your custom "go-to-my-location-button" on top of map.