# Position marker in Google Map is not disapearing when position is lost

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, position

is there are any way to make Google Map position marker disapear when position is lost and inform user about this? When I open map and turning on GPS (or mobile data/wifi), position marker (blue dot) is showing almost instantly in my last known position (I think), but if I turning off all position providers (GPS, mobile data, wifi) the blue dot stays at the same position until I close and open application again. It is possible to know if position lost and show user some kind of message? I tried to look at `onLocationChanged` method in `LocationListener` class and in `GoogleMap` method `onMyLocationChange`, but none of them not providing any info when all position providers is turned off. So, where is any way?

P.s. In official Google Maps application position marker works identical as I want.

Comment: you have to remove marker yourself using marker.remove()

Comment: I don't put position marker on map, it is placed automaticaly and I don't have reference to it, so how can I call `remove` method?

Comment: post your code for ref

Comment: I am saying, I don't have any reference to it. I have only Google Map fragment and that all. I want to know if there are any posibility to remove google map position dot when position signal is lost.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679787/android-make-disappear-or-remove-the-blue-dot-on-the-map-v2

Comment: Its answers only half of my question. But why the blue dot doesn't disapears when phone losts position signal? I am creating tracking app, and want to inform user when his position is lost, but if he looks at map, he always sees blue dot and things what warning is not correct.

Comment: i am not sure about this but i got this which might help you https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3137748?hl=en