# How to get the device heading directions like Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, location, sensors, direction

I am trying to integrate Google Maps in my Android App. I am trying to customize the way Google maps shows the device heading when rotating the device.

Is there a direct way to achieve the same ?[image]

As shown in the picture, when the device is rotated, this blue heading is also rotated which shows the device heading.

How can we achieve the same in Android?

Comment: Possible dup: [Android Make Disappear or remove the blue dot on the map v2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28679787/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang.. Question is different.. its not about changing the marker but instead rotating custom marker along with the device

Comment: The direction is determined by compass/magnetometer, possibly gyroscope. If you remove the blue dot, then you just draw your version. Otherwise I'm unclear about your question.

Comment: @MorrisonChang.. I would like to know how to use compass & magnetometer together to achieve this ?